# How to process messages in parallel from a Weblogic JMS queue?

Tags: weblogic, spring-jms

I am new to JMS, and I am trying to understand if there is a way to consume messages in parallel from a JMS queue and process them using Spring JMS.

I checked a few answers on Stack Overflow, but I am still confused.

The application I am working on uses Spring Boot and Weblogic JMS as the messaging broker. It listens to a JMS queue from a single producer using the `JmsListener` class.
In the JMS `ConnectionFactory` configuration of the application the following parameter has been set:

```java
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency("6-10");
```

Does that mean if there are 100 messages currently in a queue then 10 messages will be consumed and processed in parallel? If so, can I increase the value to process more messages in parallel? If so, are there any limitations to it?

Also, I am confused about what  `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency` and `setConcurrentConsumers` does.

Currently the processing of JMS client app is very slow. So I need suggestions to implement parallel processing.

Answer (score 1):

`concurrentConsumers` is a fixed number of consumers where as `concurrency` can specify a variable number which scale up/down as needed. Also see `maxConcurrentConsumers`.

The actual behavior also depends on prefetch; if each consumer prefetches 100 messages then only one consumer might get them all.

There is no limit (aside from memory/cpu constraints).

Comment: Thank you Gary. Apologies for the late reply.